# Highcharts stacked bar tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I've got a stacked bar chart and have a problem with tooltips. The first level of the stack is a subset of the total bar. So imagine I have gross profit=3 and sales=8 for each of a number of sales divisions. With normal stacking the far right of the bar will be 11, but I want it to be 8. I can fix that by subtracting gross profit from sales, but then the tooltips aren't right. In essence I need the gp tooltip to be this.y and the sales tooltip to be this.total, but I don't see how I can separately specify them. The data are provided to Highcharts as 2 1-D arrays with an array of categories: labels for the x-axis. Is there a way to make the tooltips work this way?

Comment: Can u put your code in a fiddle or a JS Bin ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you name the series "sales" and "profit"

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var seriesName = this.series.name;
        if(seriesName === "sales"){
          return this.total;
        }
        if(seriesName ==="profit"){
          return this.y;
        }
        return "Whatever the default case should be";
    }
},
```

Comment: Great.  Generally on Stack Overflow, if an answer was helpful its advised to upvote it and accept it so that people know your problem has been solved and know where to look if they have the same issue.